# Что означает "_" при импортировании пакета в GO?

Tags: golang

Добрый день.

Что означает "_" перед именем пакета ?

```
import _ "package"
```

Какая-то отложенная загрузка? Или что?

Про "_" как "пустой идентификатор" читал, что "Пустой идентификатор играет роль заполнителя в операции присваивания, где ожидается переменная, и помогает просто отбросить присваиваемое значение." Но какую роль этот символ играет при импортировнии пакета?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На го не пишу, но вот вам [определение из спеки](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Import_declarations):

> To import a package solely for its side-effects (initialization), use the blank identifier as explicit package name:
>
> ```
>   import _ "lib/math"
> ```

Импорт пакета только ради сайд-эффектов (кода инициализации внутри пакета), а не вызова его функций.

Comment: @Nofate: 
Спасибо.
Что-то я просто не дочитал до этого момента.

Нашел еще и на русском:
"В некоторых ситуациях не требуется явно использовать пакет, но
желательно, чтобы его функция init() была выполнена.
Для каждого из этих пакетов в качестве псевдонима указан пустой идентификатор, поэтому компилятор Go не будет выдавать предупреждения о неиспользуемых пакетах."